# Quotes in PHP classes How to use them?

Tags: php, url, escaping

I want to make variables and methods in php class. And want to use double quotes as I always use not in OOP. But it doesn't work, it shows an error. Why? Here's my code:

```
class myClass {
     public $url = "http://www.somesite.com?index=$number";     // this var has url as a value  

     public $html = "<div>                                      // this var is an HTML code with $url var in href
                        <a href='$url'>Link</a>
                     </div>"; 

     public function echoHTML() {                              // and this is method to echo html code
          echo $this->html;
     }
}

$obj = new myClass();
$obj->echoHTML();
```

Problems are:

1) It shows error if double quotes are used here

```
public $url = "http://www.somesite.com?index=$number";
```

When I change double quotes for single quotes it works fine

```
public $url = 'http://www.somesite.com?index=$number';
```

Why? I used to always use double quotes in such not OPP coding and wouldn't like to change my practice. Or I have to because single quotes are necessary in PHP OOP?

Also the same situation with the second variable $html. It makes me change outer double quotes for single quotes. And inner single qoutes to double ones. Like this:

```
public $html = '<div>                                      
                    <a href="$url">Link</a>
                </div>';
```

Ok, I change but here appears problem #2.

2) It doesn't see value of variable in href. When page is loaded there's `$url` in url but not `http://www.somesite.com?index=$number` as I expect. How to make him use a value of variable but not it's name?

Comment: There are a lot of problems with your approach to OOP, as you're basically trying to write a script within a class (which is not how OOP works). I'd suggest consulting PHP.net for OOP tutorials/examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of single vs double quotes has nothing to do with OOP or classes.

Double quotes tell PHP to evaluate the contents, so you can do stuff like `echo "text $var text";`.  When you use single quotes, the contents is not evaluated so this would not work.

Concatenating strings generally gives a performance advantage over double quotes, so single quotes are usually advisable when combining text and variables, as you are.  So consider this:

```
public $url  = 'http://www.somesite.com?index=' . $number;
public $html = '<div><a href=\"' . $url . '\">Link</a></div>';
```

Notice that you must escape the double quotes in the anchor tag.  It's also convention to use double quotes for attribute values.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you can't do that. It only works for simple expressions. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).
when you using single quote it won't evaluate as it directly *echo* the content.If you use double quote it'll get evaluate.Simple!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware you shouldn't have any problems with quotes in PHP.

What you MIGHT have problems with (and I don't know, but it looks likely) is undefined variables.

As far as I can see `$number` isn't a variable anywhere that you've defined, also `$var` isn't a variable. This could be a problem. When you switch to single quotes instead of double quotes you're including the **string** "$number" and the **string** "$var". When you've got double quotes it is looking for the variable, which I assume it cannot find.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE** - just reading back over your questions. Your second question is because you're using the variable `$var` and not `$url` which you've defined as a class variable. Secondly I'm not sure (I could be wrong) that you can use class variables in other class variables as you've done.

Comment: Yes, sorry. There's my mistake. There is $url in href of link instead of $var. I have corrected it already.